# if(img_count == 1){ $(this).attr("src",

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rollover, mousehover

I'm trying to use jQuery to do a rollover of 4 images.  Here's my current code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
jQuery('.custom_gallery_1.et_pb_gallery_item').each(function(img_count) {
     img_count++;
     var image_src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

     $(this).find('img').hover(function () {
console.log(img_count);
            //change the images by the number
            if(img_count == 1) 
                $(this).attr("src","URL to image");
            }, function () {
             $(this).attr("src", image_src);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

It's working for 1 image.  How would I rewrite this to work for 4 images. An if, else if, else? Stumped.

Can anyone help out? Thanks a ton in advanced.
- Pat.

Comment: Have you tried without 'find' just do $('img').hover()

Comment: no. It works as is now. I just need it to work with 4 images in a row. Perhaps I don't know what you mean. I will try it thanks.

Comment: OK. tried it. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Thanks a lot, though. I truly appreciate your response. I have been batting this about for awhile.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where the "URL to image" is coming from, but if they are stored in an array you could do something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/d47gary2/  Or you can dynamically build the array of the urls by pushing them to the array.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will give it a try. Much appreciated!

Comment: Awesome. It totally worked. Thanks so very much!!!!